# Can I reuse existing fields as Sharded timestamps in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

I was looking for a solution to Firestore's limitation of Sequential indexed fields which means the following from this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/shard-timestamp).

> "Sequential indexed fields" means any collection of documents that
> contains a monotonically increasing or decreasing indexed field. In
> many cases, this means a timestamp field, but any monotonically
> increasing or decreasing field value can trigger the write limit of
> 500 writes per second.

As per the solution, I can add a `shard` field in my collection which will contain random value and create a composite index with the timestamp. I am trying to achieve this with the existing fields I have in my `Document`.

My document has the following fields:

```
{
   users: string[],
   createdDate: Firebase Timestamp
   ....
}
```

I already have a composite index created: `users Arrays createdDate Descending`. Also, I have created Exemptions for the fields field from `Automatic index settings`. The `users` field will contain a list of firebase auto-generated IDs so definitely its random. Now I am not sure whether the field `users` will do the job of field `shard` form the example doc. In this way we can avoid adding a new field and still increase the write rate. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

While I don't have specific experience that says what you're trying to do definitely will or will not work the way you expect, I would assume that it works, based on the fact that the documentation says (emphasis mine):

> Add a shard field alongside the timestamp field. Use 1..n **distinct values** for the shard field. This raises the write limit for the collection to 500*n, but you must aggregate n queries.

If each `users` array contains different and essentially random user IDs, then the array field values would be considered "distinct" (as two arrays are only equal if their elements are all equal to each other), and therefore suitable for sharding.

Comment: I asked the firebase team this question, and they confirmed this. This answer should be the accepted answer.